# Vb.net - Date : How to get start time and end time of the day

Tags: vb.net

How can we accomplish this in vb.net : Get the start of day time and end of day time

For e.g.

```
Start DateTime: 05-Nov-2013 00:00:00
End DateTime: 05-Nov-2013 23:59:99
```

Regars

Comment: Note you can't have 99 seconds in a minute - i'm guessing this is a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a date value like this:

```
Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Dim startTime As DateTime = dateValue.Date + New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) 'timespan addition not actually needed here
Dim endTime As DateTime = dateValue.Date + New TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim start As DateTime = yourDate.Date
Dim endTime As DateTime = yourDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My $.02

```
    Dim someDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim StartDateTime As DateTime = someDate.Date
    'last measurable instant for a given date
    Dim EndDateTime As DateTime = someDate.Date.Add(New TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay - 1))
```